# In Javascript, one div's "background image" value must be equal to the second div's

Tags: javascript

I have two "divs", the first with the "class" name "imgHouse" - the second with the "class" name "houseImg". "background image" of "imgHouse" has an image and "background image" of "houseImg" has no image. Now I need to put the image from "imgHouse" into the "background image" of "houseImg" via javascript. But how?

## I tried the following in javascript:

`**houseImg.style.backgroundImage = imgHouse.style.backgroundImage;**`
`**houseImg.style.backgroundImage = imgHouse;**`

Comment: Perhaps `houseImg.style.backgroundImage = getComputedStyle(imgHouse).backgroundImage`

Comment: tester.html:752 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
    at tester.html:752:18

Comment: Then the issue is your script is running before the elements exist. Try moving your `<script>` right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Please post your code and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You use the property `style` with DOM elements. **houseImg** and **imgHouse** are classes in you case and not DOM elements. So you need first to select the elements before applying `style` on each.

### Correct code:

```js
document.querySelector(".houseImg").style.backgroundImage = document.querySelector(".imgHouse").style.backgroundImage
```

Comment: It hasn't changed

Comment: Did you link your JS file to the html one where  the divs are defined? This is done through a `<script>` tag